# Password validation in Mac OS X app

Tags: macos, cocoa, password-protection, amazon-dynamodb

I'm using DynamoDB to save my users and their passwords.
Now I currently make a request to get the user and his password from the database and I check on the clients side if the password was correct.
I've thought some more about it and you could probably see the password with a network-sniffer. But when I make a server-side validation, I would still have to upload the password to the server, so same effect.

I also thought about one-way hashes, which apparently aren't safe either.

Isn't there a better way to authenticate.
In my app, safety is an important aspect.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Passwords should always be salted and hashed - never store plain text passwords! If your users are authenticating to a remote server, use an encrypted channel (SSL / HTTPS) when transmitting the credentials.

Comment: Ok, which hash do you recommend?

Comment: And where should I hash it? server-side or client-side?

Comment: My domain is PHP web applications where I use phpass (bcrypt hashing, server-side). Perhaps repost your question to http://security.stackexchange.com/ with details on your application technologies to get a more informed answer?

Comment: Thanks, I'm posting another question to security.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a SHA-256 Hash on the clients side and uploading the hashed password to the database.